Search Box in GridView ASP.NET
I’m working on an ASP.NET WebForms application where I want to add a search box on top of each column header in a grid. The search box is supposed to filter the grid data based on user input.
Here’s what I’ve implemented so far:

I have placed TextBox controls inside the grid’s header template for each column.

I am handling the search operation using the OnTextChanged event in the ASPX.CS file and also tried with JavaScript in the ASPX file.


Problem:
The search boxes are displayed on the grid, but I am unable to type into them. They appear to be uneditable, and I’m not sure why the input fields are not working as expected.
$(document).ready(function () {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        var rows1 = $('table#<%= Table1.ClientID %> tr:last').index() + 1;

        if (rows1 > 1) {
            // Initialize DataTable with column-based search functionality
            var table = $("#<%=Table1.ClientID%>").DataTable({
                stateSave: true,
                pagingType: "full_numbers",
                lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                dom: '<"top"Bfl>rt<"bottom"ip><"clear">',
                buttons: [
                    { extend: 'copy', className: 'btn-sm btn-default' },
                    { extend: 'excel', className: 'btn-sm btn-success', filename: function () { return getExportFileName(); } },
                    { extend: 'print', className: 'btn-sm btn-danger' }
                ],
                responsive: false,
                retrieve: false,
                ordering: false,
            });

            // Apply search on each column
            $("#<%=Table1.ClientID%> thead input.search-column").on('keyup change', function () {
                var colIndex = $(this).closest('th').index();  // Get the index of the column
                table.column(colIndex).search(this.value).draw();  // Perform search
            });
        }
    }

    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(function (evt, args) {
        var rows1 = $('table#<%= Table1.ClientID %> tr:last').index() + 1;

        if (rows1 > 1) {
            var table = $("#<%=Table1.ClientID%>").DataTable({
                stateSave: true,
                pagingType: "full_numbers",
                lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                dom: '<"top"Bfl>rt<"bottom"ip><"clear">',
                buttons: [
                    { extend: 'copy', className: 'btn-sm btn-default' },
                    { extend: 'excel', className: 'btn-sm btn-success', filename: function () { return getExportFileName(); } },
                    { extend: 'print', className: 'btn-sm btn-danger' }
                ],
                responsive: false,
                retrieve: false,
                ordering: false,
            });

            // Apply search on each column on initial load
            $("#<%=Table1.ClientID%> thead input.search-column").on('keyup change', function () {
                var colIndex = $(this).closest('th').index();
                table.column(colIndex).search(this.value).draw();
            });
        }
    });
});


Without seeing your markup, it becomes very difficult to guess or see why your textboxes can't receive the focus.
I as a general rule suggest you place the search (and controls) above the GridView, and not place them in the header. Keep in mind that when you re-bind the GridView, the control values will be lost when such controls are in the heading (they don't persist when you re-bind the data of which you be doing for the filter).
However, here is a working GridView example:
Markup:
        <asp:GridView ID="GVHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover" Width="50%">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblFirst" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        First Name<br />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchFirst" runat="server"
                            OnTextChanged="txtSearchFirst_TextChanged"
                            AutoPostBack="true">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblLast" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        Last Name<br />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchLast" runat="server"
                            OnTextChanged="txtSearchLast_TextChanged"
                            AutoPostBack="true">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblHotel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        Hotel<br />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchHotel" runat="server"
                            OnTextChanged="txtSearchHotel_TextChanged"
                            AutoPostBack="true">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
            </Columns>                
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" style="border:none"></asp:TextBox>

And code behind is:
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string strSQL =
                "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA " +
                "ORDER BY HotelName";

            DataTable rstData = General.MyRst(strSQL);
            GVHotels.DataSource = rstData;
            GVHotels.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void txtSearchFirst_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadGrid(sender);
        
    }

    protected void txtSearchLast_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadGrid(sender);
    }

    protected void txtSearchHotel_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadGrid(sender);
    }

    void LoadGrid(object sender)
    {
        TextBox cSend = (TextBox)sender;

        TextBox sFirst = (TextBox)GVHotels.HeaderRow.FindControl("txtSearchFirst");
        TextBox sLast = (TextBox)GVHotels.HeaderRow.FindControl("txtSearchLast");
        TextBox sHotel = (TextBox)GVHotels.HeaderRow.FindControl("txtSearchHotel");

        string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ";
        string strWhere = "";

        SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("");

        if (sFirst.Text != "")
        {
            strWhere = "(FirstName LIKE @First + '%') ";
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@First", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = sFirst.Text;
        }

        if (sLast.Text != "")
        {
            if (strWhere != "") strWhere += " AND ";

            strWhere += "(LastName LIKE @Last + '%') ";
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Last", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =sLast.Text;
        }

        if (sHotel.Text != "")
        {
            if (strWhere != "") strWhere += " AND ";

            strWhere += "(HotelName LIKE @Hotel + '%') ";
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Hotel", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =sHotel.Text;
        }

        if (strWhere != "") strWhere = " WHERE " + strWhere;

        cmdSQL.CommandText = strSQL + strWhere + " ORDER BY HotelName";

        GVHotels.DataSource = General.MyRstP(cmdSQL);
        GVHotels.DataBind();

        // with a grid re-bind, then the header text boxes are lost, so lets 
        // restore them

        TextBox sFirstR = (TextBox)GVHotels.HeaderRow.FindControl("txtSearchFirst");
        TextBox sLastR = (TextBox)GVHotels.HeaderRow.FindControl("txtSearchLast");
        TextBox sHotelR = (TextBox)GVHotels.HeaderRow.FindControl("txtSearchHotel");

        sFirstR.Text = sFirst.Text;
        sLastR.Text = sLast.Text;
        sHotelR.Text = sHotel.Text;

        // we assume user just hit tab key, and with a post-back then text box focus
        // will be re-set, so let's move cursor to the next text box in the gv header
        if (cSend.ID == "txtSearchFirst") sLastR.Focus();
        if (cSend.ID == "txtSearchLast") sHotelR.Focus();
        if (cSend.ID == "txtSearchHotel") sFirstR.Focus();

    }

And thus the result is this:

Note how we have to "restore" the text boxes if we re-bind the GridView. If you place the controls outside of the GridView, then such code will not be required.
